# Возможна ли сериализация несериализуемого объекта?

Tags: c#, сериализация

При попытке сериализовать такой объект программа валится с ошибкой:

> Тип CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcStruct в сборке CookComputing.XmlRpcV2,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d6e17aa302004d не
>   отмечен как сериализуемый.

можно ли как то обойти это и сериализовать объект такого типа?
У меня нет доступа к изменению свойств этого типа.

Буду рада, если мне подскажете например другие способы распаковать и увидеть то что пришло от сервера

```
[XmlRpcUrl("https://blabala.com/rpc")] // описание методов
public interface Trac : IXmlRpcProxy            
{       
    [XmlRpcMethod("ticket.get")]  //
    object[] get(int id);

    [XmlRpcMethod("ticket.getActions")]  //
    object[] getActions(int id);
}

public partial class DHL : Form
{
    public DHL()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 6;                  
        get(id);
    }

    private void get(int id)
    {
        Trac proxy;
        string user = "uzer";
        string password = "parol";
        proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<Trac>();
        proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password);
         object[] arr = proxy.get(id);
         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("arr.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
          {
              formatter.Serialize(fs, arr);// тут и ошибка, что Тип CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcStruct в сборке CookComputing.XmlRpcV2, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d6e17aa302004d не отмечен как сериализуемый.
          }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 6;            
        getActions( id);
    }

    private void getActions(int id)
    {
        Trac proxy;
        string user = "uzer";
        string password = "parol";
        proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<Trac>();
        proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password);
        object[]  arr = proxy.getActions(id);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("arr.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, arr);//а тут нет такой ошибки
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код будем показывать? У нас тут как у врача -- стесняться не нужно. Вываливайте.

Comment: Вообще проблема моя немного в другом. Я через XMLRPS подучаю данные от удалённого сервера. В object[] их записываю, но потом не знаю как их увидеть. Для метода getAction прокатил способ провести сериализацию и увидеть полученный пакет. А для метода get такое не получается.

Comment: сейчас код прикреплю

Answer (score 5):

Нашел решение на [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166105/is-it-possible-to-do-net-binary-serialization-of-an-object-when-you-dont-have), далее вольный перевод:

Можно создать serialization surrogate.

Например, у нас есть такой класс

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DriversLicense License;
}


// An instance of this type will be part of the object graph and will need to be 
// serialized also.
public class DriversLicense
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо создать суррогат для каждого объекта в графе объектов.

Для этого необходимо реализовать интерфейс [`ISerializationSurrogate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class PersonSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Manually add objects to the <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> store.
    /// </summary>
    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Person person = (Person) obj;
        info.AddValue("Name", person.Name);
        info.AddValue("Age", person.Age);
        info.AddValue("License", person.License);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves objects from the <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> store.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        Person person = (Person)obj;
        person.Name = info.GetString("Name");
        person.Age = info.GetInt32("Age");
        person.License = (DriversLicense) info.GetValue("License", typeof(DriversLicense));
        return person;
    }
}

public class DriversLicenseSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Manually add objects to the <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> store.
    /// </summary>
    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        DriversLicense license = (DriversLicense)obj;
        info.AddValue("Number", license.Number);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves objects from the <see cref="SerializationInfo"/> store.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        DriversLicense license = (DriversLicense)obj;
        license.Number = info.GetString("Number");
        return license;
    }
}
```

Далее тебе нужен [`IFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter(v=vs.110).aspx), который знает о твоих суррогатах им им нужно инициализировать [`SurrogateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static void SerializePerson(Person person)
{
    if (person == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("person");

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //Configure our surrogate selectors.
        var surrogateSelector = new SurrogateSelector();
        surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof (Person), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All),
                                       new PersonSurrogate());
        surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof (DriversLicense), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All),
                                       new DriversLicenseSurrogate());

        //Serialize the object
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.SurrogateSelector = surrogateSelector;
        formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, person);

        //Return to the beginning of the stream
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Deserialize the object
        Person deserializedPerson = (Person) formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Если необходимо сериализовать защищенные и приватные поля, то задача может решаться несколько сложнее. Подозреваю, что придется пользоваться рефлексией и ручками брать\присваивать значения из недоступных свойств...

---

Еще интересное мнение по этому поводу [нашел](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0879ab3e-f195-483d-aef4-1d9637b135d3/how-to-serialize-a-non-sertilizable-object-into-binary?forum=netfxremoting):

Суть в том, что не всегда-это реализуемо. Например, контролы Windows Forms хранят хэндлы ОС=> при десериализации на другой машине все скорее всего упадет. Наверное, можно и это учесть с помощью WinApi, но это уже изврат.

---

Рихтер в своей книге хорошо описывает процесс сераиализации несериализуемых объектов. В том числе приводится пример с суррогатами.

Comment: строка person.Name = info.GetString("Name");
не проходит с типом CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcStruct((

Comment: @404, задача не так проста как кажется и в ней много нюансов. Я бы для начала сделал бы свой собственный класс со всеми возможными сценариями, например закрытые поля, наследование и т п. После того, как вы набили руку перешел бы к реальной задаче. В ответе описывается банальный пример.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение своей задачи с помощью DataTable

```
        object[] arr = proxy.get(id); //момент получения данных
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        XmlRpcStruct arr3 = (XmlRpcStruct)arr[3];//проблема у меня была с выводом 3 его элемента объекта, поэтому его и преобразовываем
        XmlRpcStruct[] arr33 = new XmlRpcStruct[1];
        arr33[0] = arr3;


        dt = StructArrayToDT(arr33);//преобразуем в DataTable

        //DA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;//полученный DataTable можно вывести в DataGrid

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + arr[0] + "\r\n" + arr[1] + "\r\n" + arr[2] + "\r\n";// тут выводим 0-2 члены объекта, с которыми не было проблем
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();//можно сериализовать полученный DataTable
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("arr.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, dt);
        }




   public static DataTable StructArrayToDT(XmlRpcStruct[] data) //метод который из XmlRpcStruct[] делает DataTable
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (data.Length == 0) { return dt; }

        // do columns
        foreach (DictionaryEntry d in data[0])
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(d.Key.ToString(), typeof(object));
        }

        foreach (XmlRpcStruct xmlstruct in data)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry d in xmlstruct)
            {
                try
                {
                    dr[d.Key.ToString()] = d.Value;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // handle errors
                }

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```